# System.Web.HttpCompileException - External Component throws an excepetion

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a newbie in ASP.NET MVC and is working on a code, that have worked on a previous page that I've done but when I used it on another page, it is suddenly not working anymore. It is supposed to display a set of records to be chosen and displayed on a modal. Once I run the code, it keeps on this error - "System.Web.HttpCompileException - External Component throws an Excepetion"

Here is my code on the my Controller:

```
    public ActionResult DROrders()
    {
        var model = new OSSelectionViewModel();
        foreach (var dr in deliveryRepo.GetDROrders())
        {
            var editorViewModel = new SelectOSEditorViewModel()
            {
                ORDER_ID = dr.ORDER_ID,
                ORDER_NUMBER = dr.ORDER_NUMBER,
                ORDER_DATE = dr.ORDER_DATE,
                ORDER_DUE_DATE = dr.ORDER_DUE_DATE,
                CUSTOMER_ID = dr.CUSTOMER_ID,
                CUSTOMER_NAME = dr.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                LOCATION_TYPE_ID = dr.LOCATION_TYPE_ID,
                LOCATION_TYPE_NAME = dr.LOCATION_TYPE_NAME,
                ADDRESS = dr.ADDRESS,
                EMP_ID = dr.EMP_ID,
                EMP_FIRST_NAME = dr.EMP_FIRST_NAME,
                EMP_LAST_NAME = dr.EMP_LAST_NAME,
                NET_AMOUMT = dr.NET_AMOUNT,
                Selected = false
            };
            model.drselect.Add(editorViewModel);
        }
        return View(model);

    }





    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DROrders(OSSelectionViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {

            int[] selectedIds = model.getSelectedIds().ToArray();
            int num = selectedIds.Length;
            int tmp;

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {

                tmp = selectedIds[i];
                listDrOrder.Add(tmp);
                testVar = testVar + 1;
                listDROrder.AddRange(dritemrepo.GetDROrderdetailItem(tmp));

            }

            drstoreId = listDrOrder.ToArray();


            TempData["listDROrder"] = listDROrder;
            TempData.Peek("listDROrder");



            return RedirectToAction("AddDR");

        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }

        return View(model);

    }
```

Here are my View Models:

OSSelectionViewModel:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ebms_2.Models
{
    public class OSSelectionViewModel
    {
        public List<SelectOSEditorViewModel> drselect { get; set; }
        public OSSelectionViewModel()
        {
            this.drselect = new List<SelectOSEditorViewModel>();
        }

        public int[] getSelectedIds()
        {
            // Return an Enumerable containing the Id's of the selected items:
            return (from dr in this.drselect where dr.Selected select dr.ORDER_ID).ToArray();
        }

    }
}
```

And these are my Views ..

SelectOSEditorViewModel.cshtml:

```html
@model ebms_2.Models.SelectOSEditorViewModel

@*@{
        ViewBag.Title = "SelectOSEditorViewModel";
    }*@

<tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ORDER_ID)
    <td style="text-align:center">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Selected, new { @class = "chkitem" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ORDER_ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ORDER_NUMBER)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ORDER_DATE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ORDER_DUE_DATE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CUSTOMER_NAME)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LOCATION_TYPE_NAME)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ADDRESS)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FULL_NAME)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NET_AMOUNT)
    </td>

</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var items = new Array();
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            items.push($(this).val());
        });

        $('#submit').click(function () {
            alert(items);
        });

    });// document ready


</script>
```

and

```html
@model ebms_2.Models.OSSelectionViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DROrders";

    
if (ViewBag.Samp != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in ViewBag.Samp)
        {

<p style="font-weight:bold; color:red; font-size:large;">
    @item.PRODUCT_ID
    @item.PRODUCT_CODE
    @item.QUANTITY_ORDERED
    @item.MEASUREMENT_ID
    @item.MEASUREMENT_NAME
    @item.tmpStatus
</p>
        }
    }

}



<div class="container">
    <h2>Orders</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("DROrders", "Sales", FormMethod.Post))
    {

        // Wrap the table element in a div named "checkboxes":
        <div id="checkboxes">
            <table id="tbl_drOrders" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Select
                        </th>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>
                            O.S. No.
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Order Date
                        </th>
                        <th>Due Date</th>
                        <th>Customer Id</th>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Location Type Id</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Emp Id</th>
                        <th>Sales Person</th>
                        <th>Amount Due</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.drselect)
            </table>
            
        </div>
        <hr />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="operation" id="submitbutton" value="Submit Selected" />
    }
</div>

<span id="spanResults"></span>
```

The error points to this line of code:

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.drselect)
```

What seems to be the problem? Hope someone can help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is drSelect supposed to be?

Comment: @denchu its a var where I pass on the content of the SelectOSEditorViewModel . It's where I list it.

Comment: @denchu my concern Sir, is that it is perfectly working on where I first used it but when I recycled this code, it keeps throwing that error.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding your application and restart the IIS?

Comment: @denchu not yet actually, let me just try that Sir and I will update you on the result. Thank you!

Comment: @denchu I have tried what you have suggested sir. Unfortunately, it still returns the same error.